# Is there still any reason to use SafeERC20Upgradeable with the ERC20Upgradeable?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

**From the ERC20Upgradeable docs:**
"We have followed general OpenZeppelin Contracts guidelines:
functions revert instead returning `false` on failure. This behavior is nonetheless
conventional and does not conflict with the expectations of ERC20 applications. "

**From the SafeERC20Upgradeable contract:**
"Wrappers around ERC20 operations that throw on failure (when the token contract returns `false`). Tokens that return no value (and instead revert or throw on failure) are also supported, non-reverting calls are assumed to be successful."

**My Question:**
Seems that if I use the ERC20Upgradeable token I don't need the SafeERC20Upgradeable wrapper in my contracts anymore, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are completely different things.

**ERC20Upgradeable** is a basis contract that you can build on top to make your own ERC20 token.

**SafeERC20Upgradeable** is a library you can use to interact with *others* ERC20 contracts. This is actually [the same as SafeERC20](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/safeerc20-vs-safeerc20upgradeable/17326).